# Last name in my passport is different from documents to be submitted for Schengen visa

Tags: schengen-visas

I am applying for a Greek Schengen visa. My passport's last name is different from the one in my documents, due to native tongue. Will I have any problem getting the visa?

Comment: If you explain them then No.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to include a brief explanation of which supporting documents have a variation from your name as it appears in your passport (which would be the same as in a visa, if granted). Depending on how they differ, you may want to explain how they are yours, although most consular officials are accustomed to seeing global variations to naming conventions and practices. In itself, this should not adversely affect a visa application.